# Is $d(f(x))=xf'(x)/f(x)$ a useful indicator of the growth of a function?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, asymptotics, monotone-functions

I suppose the following observation is not unique, though I don't think I have seen it.

For the monomial $p(x)=x^n$ we have $n= \dfrac {xp'(x)}{p(x)}$ and for $p(x)$ a polynomial we can extract the degree as an asymptotic limit. This I noticed when playing around with the functions in another question on this site.

For the exponential function $f(x)=e^{ax}$ we have $ax=\dfrac {xf'(x)}{f(x)}$, and testing other simple functions gives similar results.

So I have been looking at the "degree" function $$d\left(f(x)\right)=\dfrac {xf'(x)}{f(x)}$$and wondering whether it extracts any useful/reliable information about more general (real valued) functions (of a real variable) $f(x)$ at least in cases where they are eventually monotonic. Also whether it might offer a test of comparative growth rates which could be proved more readily than the individual cases of complicated functions.

So I'm looking for basic wisdom and any references and whether there are obvious examples of failure. Also whether there might be a definition which would work sensibly with, for example $f(x)=\sin x$, which is the example which suggested the "eventually monotonic" restriction.

Comment: I really don't understand the title. The LHS is a differential and hence infinitesimally small whereas the RHS can be finite. So how are they equal?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Both sides are functions in $x$ which may be constant.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta I am not meaning $d(f(x))$ as a differential but simply as a function $d(x)$ apologies if the notation was misleading. I used $d$ for degree. $d$ can also be regarded as a function of $f(x)$ which is the interpretation I am thinking of.

Comment: Oh I get it now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: There is something interesting here, such as $d(\log(x))=\frac1{\log(x)}$ so slowly decreasing towards $0$ and so of almost no degree, and $d(\frac{x}{x+1})=\frac1{x+1}$ so quickly decreasing towards $0$ and so of even smaller degree.  On the faster growing side $d(x^x)=x(1+\log(x))$ so growing a bit faster than exponential functions, and  $d(\exp(x^2/2))=x^2$ so a step up from exponential functions, and  $d\left(e^{e^x}\right)=xe^x$ so well beyond exponential functions.